# Dynamic predicates and functions and cost of functional approach

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm starting to get acquainted with Java and there are some features which I really like, e.g. using `Predicate` with `.filter()` and `Function` with `.map()`. This is a really nice functional approach. I have three questions about this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class ProcessList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 3, 2, 14, 1, -1, 0, 1, 5, 9, 0, 1);
        Predicate<Integer> gt3 = (n) -> n > 3;
        Function<Integer, Integer> plus11 = (n) -> n + 11;

        List<Integer> numbersProcessed = numbers
                .stream()
                .filter(gt3)
                .map(plus11)
                .toList();
    }
}
```

1. Regarding `Predicate`: at the moment the number `3` is hard-coded. Say I want a dynamic predicate which is created at runtime, e.g. `(n) -> n > x`, with `x` being some Integer. How could I create a dynamic Predicate object? I tried something using `new Predicate()`, but this didn't seem right.
2. Same as 1. regarding `Function`: say I don't want plus `11`, but `(n) -> n + x`, with `x` being some Integer supplied at runtime. How can I create a dynamic Function object?
3. The `.filter()`, `.map()`, and `.toList()` operations make me think: Java is not a functional language by design. Since the essence of functional languages is to manipulate lists all the time, those languages are optimized to constantly produce new lists from existing lists, the more so as functional languages do not allow in-place manipulations on objects in principle. I was wondering: say there is a large list, containing millions of items. Will these kinds of list manipulations have a significant impact on Java's performance? In essence: what is the cost of using the functional approach in Java?

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for comment. I wouldn't use this code in an application either. I just wanted to supply a executable example for reference.

Comment: there are lot of videos of conferences about the cost of functional programming on the web, and they will explain it way better... for the other 2 questions, you can just have the `x` variable in the method and access it inside the lambda, however this would be against functional programming because you are referencing something that can change in time (like a global variable)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Oh please. You can't learn computer programming from YouTube. There is plenty of official documentation and tutorial material availalble, and books.

Comment: You don't need to declare variables of type `Predicate`, `Function`, etc. You can just write `.filter(n -> n > x)` where `x` is any final or effectively-final local variable or method parameter, or a class or instance variable. No need for extra methods. Similarly you can write `.map(n -> n+y)`  where `y` is 11 or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method like this:

```
Predicate<Integer> gt(Integer number) {
    return (n) -> n > number;
}
```

And use a `Map<Integer, Predicate<Integer>>` to store these values. You can implement a getter like this:

```
Predicate<Integer> getGt(Map<Integer, Predicate<Integer>> gtMap, Integer key) {
    if (!gtMap.containsKey(key)) gtMap.put(key, gt(key));
    return gtMap.get(key);
}
```

As about the third question, I recommend doing some experiments and reading some articles about it.

Comment: Both these can be one-liners. No methods required.

Comment: @user207421 true. But my experience is that code likely to be reused is best written in its own method, to avoid code duplication and large, dicey refactorization.